# Button in tip view create by EasyTipView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using EasyTipView to create a custom tip view have a button inside look like the image below. But notthing happen when I click to button inside tip view. Does anyone have use this libray and know how to fix this problem ?

My demo:  github.com/minhtien1403/TestTipView

Library link: https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView

[image]

View hierarchy is fine, nothing overlay the button

[image: View hierarchy is fine, nothing overlay the button]

Comment: Can you share demo project link in your question?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni sure, you can see a demo in this link https://github.com/minhtien1403/TestTipView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from your github demo, I notice things make button click inside not working.

First of all, in your `CustomTipView` when ever you change to position, you call `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to redefine view which make the xib not working correctly anymore. Just need to remove this

```swift
fileprivate func arrange(withinSuperview superview: UIView) {
       // your others code
       if case .view(let contentView) = content {
            contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // remove this
            contentView.frame = getContentRect(from: getBubbleFrame())
        }
       // your others code
}
```

Comment: Have you test it ? If i set the delegate and enable tap gesture, i can receive tap event when i tap to tip view, but the button is still not working. In my demo i try to remove tap gesture because i think it maybe conflict with button but when I remove the gesture, my button is still untappble

Comment: Dear @TienTranMinh, yes I've tested it. Do you change ``showTip`` as I describe above? Don't remove the gesture please. Just add the delegate and everything will work fine

Comment: Yeah I have do exactly what you tell me but when I click to button, the only text I saw is "dismiss". What i expect is "Tap to button" show up. Can you make a PR to my demo pr please

Comment: Hello, I had test your code, it only take the action when tap to tip view. If you check inside UsageToolTipView.swift you will see I add an action to show "Tap on button" text when tap to button, and this is still not working with your code

Comment: Dear @TienTranMinh, I found your problem. Check update code or github